# Why does my child process hang when the stdout is redirected to write pipe?

Tags: c, while-loop, pipe, file-descriptor, freeze

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int k;
    char a[32];
    char b[32] = "1\n\0";
    char c[32] = "2\n\0";
    char d[32] = "3\n\0";

    k = fork();

    if (k == 0) {
        dup2(fd[0], fileno(stdin));
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], fileno(stdout)); // Commenting this out will fix the hanging. Why?
        close(fd[1]);
        while (read(fileno(stdin), a, sizeof(a)) > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "PID %d is printing %s", getpid(), a);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1], b, sizeof(b));
    write(fd[1], c, sizeof(c));
    write(fd[1], d, sizeof(d));
    close(fd[1]);

    return 0;
```

}

While loop never finishes, and the child process hangs when `stdout` is redirected.

Also, is `read` the right option in the while loop? It is a good option because the parent is calling `write` right? Or should I be using `fgets` or something similar because it is reading from pipe as if from `stdin`?

Comment: As long as there are processes that have an open file descriptor to the write-end of the pipe, `read()` from the read-end of the pipe will not return `0` to indicate end-of-file. Instead, the `read()` will block until the pipe is written to, or the last writer closes the write-end. Unfortunately, the `dup2(pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO)` keeps a file-descriptor to the write end *in the process blocked on `read()`*, self-deadlocking the `read()`.

Comment: The dup2 is a red herring. If you do not connect stdio to your pipe, the process will still hang.

Comment: The `\0` at the end of the strings is immaterial; C puts a second one after the one you specify explicitly.

Comment: @EOF So I should never do it this way?

Comment: @ludluck: Why do you even `dup2()` the write end? You don't seem to need it for anything.

Comment: The example compiled for me on Linux and the Mac and in both cases it didn't hang.

Comment: @EOF I will be using it later.

Comment: @Harry Yes it seems to be working for some...